# aterm with DejaVu Sans mono font

Tags: command-line, fonts

How can I tell aterm to use DejaVu Sans Mono as the default font?

I'm aware of two ways how to specify a font for a term:

1. Start with `aterm -fn FONTNAME`
2. Put `Aterm*font: FONTNAME` in `~/.Xdefaults`

What is the correct fontname of DejaVu Sans Mono? I tried some values like `"-*-dejavu sans mono-medium-r-normal--*-80-*-*-*-*-iso10646-1"`, but aterm complains `can't load font`.

The APT package `fonts-dejavu` is installed, however I can't find any font family namend "DejaVu" in `xfontsel`. On the other hand, `LXTerminal` is using DejaVu Sans, so I assume the font is installed correctly.

Comment: "DejaVu Sans Mono" is the correct font name.

Comment: If I run `aterm -fn "DejaVu Sans Mono"` I still get `can't load font "DejaVu Sans Mono"`. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Can't tell - I don't use aterm. Just wanted to confirm the font name.